# SharedPreferences: put default value or remove key?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

What is best solution (minimization of: memory, processor time and file i/o operations) for the SharedPreferences: put default value or remove key?

```
int getKeyValue(Context context) {
    //FILE_NAME - file name, KEY - key, 0 default value for key
    return context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt(KEY, 0);
}
```

**1st choice:**

```
//FILE_NAME - file name, KEY - key, 0 default value for key
context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt(KEY, 0).apply();
```

**2nd choice:**

```
//FILE_NAME - file name, KEY - key, 0 default value for key
context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(KEY).apply();
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Also, for info. To save yourself from repeating the line context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit() you can just tag the call to apply() to the end of the first statement in each of your examples.

Comment: @IvanWooll Minimization of: memory, processor time and file i/o operations

Comment: The difference would be negligible. Not worth worrying about unless you're carrying out that operation thousands of times in a short space of time IMHO

Comment: @IvanWooll Please don't forget that it's not only memory-processor, there **file i/o operations**